# How can a row be read when the table is read/write locked?

Tags: mysql, innodb, isolation-level, readwritelock

I am running these queries on MySQL 5.6.13.
I using repeatable read isolation level. The table looks like below:

[image]

In Session A terminal I have issued below statement

```
UPDATE manufacurer
SET lead_time = 2
WHERE mname = 'Hayleys';
```

In Session B terminal I tried to update the value lead_time of ACL Cables to 2. But since the previous UPDATE command from Session A is not yet committed (and Session A has an exclusive lock on manufacturer table), this update waits. This I can understand.

But when I try to execute a SELECT statement on Session B as below,

```
SELECT * FROM manufacturer
WHERE mcode = 'ACL';
```

it correctly query the manufacturer table and give out the row. How can this happen? Because Session A still hold the exclusive lock on manufacturer table and as I understand when an exclusive lock is held on a table no other transactions can **read from or write to** it till the previous transaction is committed.

Comment: In the title of your question you distinguish between read and write lock while in the question you talk about a lock that prevents read **and** write. Please update your question / title for consistency.

Comment: Since you are not modifiying the row in the Session B. Data is returned.

Comment: @KayNelson Umm..If I understand correct eventhough I am not modifying the row, I am still trying to read from it and exclusive locks does not let other sessions to **read or write** untill the previous transaction is committed.

Comment: Are you using innodb as engine?

Comment: Do you wan't to implement that behaviour or wondering why it is already happening? Either way, refer [MySQL locking](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/internal-locking.html) docs.

Comment: @KayNelson Yes I am using innodb as engine

Comment: @alko I am wondering why it is happenning

Comment: read docs; I updated question to reflect your comments. please see if you agree with updates

Comment: @Thili InnoDB provides row level locking. Your `UPDATE` only touches the row `WHERE mname = 'Hayleys'`. Your SELECT is for data in a different row `WHERE mcode = 'ACL'`. So that row is safe to read - though this also depends on which indexes you have on your table - more rows than exactly the rows that are updated might be locked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found below information on this page

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html#isolevel_repeatable-read

**Scope of Transaction Characteristics**

> You can set transaction characteristics globally, for the current
>   session, or for the next transaction:
>
> With the GLOBAL keyword, the statement applies globally for all
>   subsequent sessions. Existing sessions are unaffected.
>
> With the SESSION keyword, the statement applies to all subsequent
>   transactions performed within the current session.
>
> Without any SESSION or GLOBAL keyword, the statement applies to the
>   next (not started) transaction performed within the current session.

Have this been taken into consideration?

**REPEATABLE READ**

> This is the default isolation level for InnoDB. For consistent reads,
>   there is an important difference from the READ COMMITTED isolation
>   level: All consistent reads within the same transaction read the
>   snapshot established by the first read. This convention means that if
>   you issue several plain (nonlocking) SELECT statements within the same
>   transaction, these SELECT statements are consistent also with respect
>   to each other.

In this article its decribes very well.

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/08/28/differences-between-read-committed-and-repeatable-read-transaction-isolation-levels/

> It is important to remember that InnoDB actually locks index entries,
>   not rows. During the execution of a statement InnoDB must lock every
>   entry in the index that it traverses to find the rows it is modifying.
>   It must do this to prevent deadlocks and maintain the isolation level.

Are the tables well indexed? Can you run a `SHOW ENGINE innodb STATUS` to confirm that the lock is held?

Answer (score 2):

There are kinds of lock in mysql: row-level lock and table-level lock.

What you need is row-level lock,which allows read the lines beyond the ones updating.

And to implement the row-level lock,you have to define the engine type of your table to 'InnoDB':

```
alter table TABLE_NAME engine=innodb;
```

Comment: Its called ROW level locking i think.